# exporting views definition using Dba tools from synapse serverless database

Tags: serverless, dbatools

i am able to export it but there are different schemas and i want to export only specific schema views.

below is the dba tools script using. How can i add filter in below statement to get only specific schema views.

Get-DbaDbview -SqlInstance $server -ExcludeSystemView | Export-DbaScript -FilePath C:\Scripts\Views.sql -Append